# Fsharp - Websharper Create some Types which are the same and include some buttons

Tags: f#, fs, f#-data, websharper

I have a Type of "Person" :

- Button A : Name
- Button B : Age
- Button C : Adres

And a button "ADD"

I want to create some "Person" when clicking to button "ADD" .
But I don't know .

I'm using Websharper . Do you know the key word that can help me ?

Comment: The keyword to help you is [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/constructors)

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: This example may be useful: https://try.websharper.com/example/todo-list. Otherwise, including some of your code would allow more specific help.